# REST Web API Design for Bulk read

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have to design an API or set of APIs which are used to read bulk data from SQL Server Table and I need to get data by date and other parameters. Now I don't want to have list of N no. of methods in the API as the list is indefinite and it will keep on increasing as per the user needs.

So how should I design this.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using the WCF Data Services and OData so that your method(s) can accept 'SQL over the wire' requests. This gives you a single URL which can accept filter criteria e.g.

// All the data from the Products table (enable paging on the server side!)

```
http://localhost/Products
```

// Add a WHERE clause

```
http://localhost/Products?$filter=Category eq 'Toys'
```

// SELECT a subset of columns

```
http://localhost/Products?$select=ToyName,ToyPrice
```

You could also use the ASP.NET Web API project type and enable OData support but the URL functionality is slightly more limited.

Having said that I would think it's unusual to use a web service for bulk data operations because of the overhead involved in data serialization and the way packets must be split up over HTTP. It depends how *bulky* your data really is.

Comment: Thanks Oli. That what my question is. I cant have 1 webapi to bring 300,000 rows at one time but I don't want to have separate get methods to get records by filtering them as per the different parameter.         Please suggest how  we can design the api to have different filters and one get.